# CSS Html display inline

Tags: html, css

Having a small problem with css, new on this website and wondering if someone could help me :),

I am trying to get the menu images to show next to eachother, but at the moment they are still being displayed below eachother.

this is the css for it, I know some is not being used but I am trying to follow a tutorial at the moment this one: http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/13-converting-a-photoshop-mockup-part-two-episode-two/

I am on 14 minutes 23 seconds..

this is my css

```
 * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
 html { overflow-y: scroll; }
 body { font: 62.5% "Helvetica", sans-serif;
 background: url(body-bg.jpg) top left repeat;}

ul { list-style: none inside; }
p { font-size: 1.2em; line-height: 1.2em; margin-bottom: 1.2em; }
a { outline: none; }
a img { border: none; }
/* END RESET */


/* TOOLBOX */
.floatleft { float: left; }
.floatright { float: right; }
.clear { clear: both; }
/* END TOOLBOX */

/* STRUCTURE AND STUFF */
#page-wrap {
width: 654px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

ul#nav {

}
ul#nav li{
    display: inline;
    }
    ul#nav li a {
        display: block;
        height: 62px;
        text-indent:-99999px

}
ul#nav li.articles a {
    width: 200px;
    background:url(nav-articles.jpg)bottom center no-repeat;
    }

ul#nav li.downloads a {
    width:287px;
    background:url(nav-downloads.jpg)bottom center no-repeat;
}
ul#nav li.videos a {
    width:167px;
    background:url(nav-videos.jpg)bottom center no-repeat;
}

/* END STRUCTURE */
```

this is my html

```
<body>


<div id="page-wrap">


<img src="header.jpg" alt="mockup header" />


    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="articles"><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
        <li class="videos"><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
        <li class="downloads"><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
    </ul>

<p>Main Content</p> 


<div id="sidebar">
</div>    

</div>

<div id=footer">
</div>


</body>
```

Thanks again for any help!!

Comment: Have you played around with Firebug, Google/IE Developer Tools? Press F12, you can edit the CSS on the fly for the element you are trying to fix and then see what rule will get the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks I have downloaded firebug and started playing with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe setting the a tag within the li to display: block is doing it. I'd suggest removing display:block from:

```
ul#nav li a {
        display: block;
        height: 62px;
        text-indent:-99999px

}
```

Or, you could add float:left to that declaration - that's where I see the difference between yours and the code in the link you posted.

Comment: float left did it, although taking display:block away is what I thought before and tried but it stops showing the images, although does put it inline any insight on that? thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 0):

Change to `display: inline-black` and add `white-space: nowrap;` (nowrap prevents the line from wrapping, but you may not need this depending on what you're doing)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `display: block;` in `ul#nav li a`

You can see how it affects it here: http://jsfiddle.net/aWNbC/

Comment: Unfortunately that took the images away, although did indeed place them inline.. any insight on why? I added float: left; and that did the job but I am still wondering why it did this